# How to use ref connect

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to call a method inside a component. In more details, this component shows a vertical page swiper, I need a button "go to the next slide". I'm trying to use `ref` but I get the error `this.refs.verticalViewPager is undefined`. I tried to print `this.refs`, **it is undefined too**.

```
class App extends Component {
  nextPage() {
        this.refs.verticalViewPager.nextPage()
    }

  render () {
    return (<VerticalViewPager ref="verticalViewPager">
     <View>
      <Text>slide one</Text>
      <Button title={"click to go to the next slide"}  onPress={this.nextPage}  />
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text>slide two</Text>
    </View>
</VerticalViewPager>)
  }
}
```

https://github.com/gy-chen/react_native_vertical_view_pager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a function instead of a string, also it might be because you're not using arrow functions or binding the nextPage method:

```
class App extends Component {
  nextPage = () => {
        this._verticalViewPager.nextPage()
    }

  render () {
    return (<VerticalViewPager ref={component => this._verticalViewPager = component}>
     <View>
      <Text>slide one</Text>
      <Button title={"click to go to the next slide"}  onPress={this.nextPage}  />
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text>slide two</Text>
    </View>
</VerticalViewPager>)
  }
}
```

Comment: using this method `this._verticalViewPager` is still undefined

Comment: Did you update the nextPage to an arrow function? `nextPage = () => {`

Comment: yes after I commented I did it :). That works, but now I get `this._startContentOffset is undefined`  this is a field of the component `VerticalViewPager`  of course..

Comment: @alfredopacino how did you solve the `this._startContentOffset is undefined`?

Comment: I will try to figure it out a proper solution. As quickfix I use `scrollTo()` method (of the same VerticalViewPager component) with the y value = Height of the screen.